# HTML код в JS без кавычек. Как это реализовано в React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

В методе ReactDOM.render React-a мы можем объявлять компоненты сразу HTML кодом. Вот так:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
    <WebPage />
</div>, 
document.getElementById('fieldToShow'));
```

Как я понимаю render() - это метод написанный на JS, а HTML передается в него как аргумент функции. Но ведь JS не может оперировать HTML кодом без кавычек.
Например, если я напишу следующий код, то само-собой получу ошибку "Unexpected token <":

```
function test(<div></div>) {}
```

Также при выводе HTML из JS функции:

```
function test(){
    return <div></div>
}
```

**У кого-нибудь есть идеи, как это реализовано в React-е?**

**Можете привести пример кода, позволяющего передавать в JS функцию HTML код в качестве аргумента, при этом не вызывая ошибки компиляции?**

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае используется не html, а jsx код, который, впрочем, очень похож на html. Подробнее можно прчесть в документации тут https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html или тут https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересная штука.

А можно ли использовать JSX без Node.js? Практически во всех туториалах по React или babel, что я находил с JSX работали через Node.js, т.е. импортировали react, react-dom и babel, а затем писали код.

Могу ли я к пустой HTML-странице через тег <script> подключить babel (или другую библиотеку), и писать код сразу на JSX?
Желательно не притягивая React вообще.

Comment: @AkaNew Конечно, вот отличный пример для демонстрации такой возможности https://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/akPrqW